# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Command'

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I have upgraded django on my project, when i am running any command like `python manage.py runserver` It shows an error like `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Command'` Is there any issue in Django or in code??

```
Django Pro\Django_Project-master\Dpro> python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Ga\Django Pro\Django_Project-master\Dpro\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Ga\Django Pro\Django_Project-master\Dpro\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Ga\Django Pro\Django_Project-master\Dpro\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 224, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Users\Ga\Django Pro\Django_Project-master\Dpro\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 37, in load_command_class
    return module.Command()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Command'
```

Comment: We will need more context regarding Command thing

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: @FlipperPA yes! but if i run the command without env,  also getting same error

Comment: @Gangesh Can you try by creating a fresh virtual environment? And if that doesn't work, amend your answer with the output of `pip freeze`?

Comment: @FlipperPA thanks! Virtual environment wasn't my problem, if I run any of the commands into virtualenv after activating into project dir [(env) PS C:\Users\Ga\Django Pro\Django_Project-master\Dpro]  it throws an above error. now i have resolve this issue.